# How to capture SignalR Response on Angular 6

Tags: angular6, signalr

I am struggling to listen to the message I am getting from a .net application using signalR on angular 6 application.

In angular.json file I have added /node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js & jquery

Package.json includes

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts": "^1.0.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/signalr": "^2.2.35",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^20.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "browser-detect": "^0.2.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-icons": "^0.2.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "signalr": "^2.4.1",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
    }
```

Service file:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SignalRServiceService {
    private connection: any;
    private proxy: any;
    private url  = 'https://localhost:8090';

    constructor() {}

    public startConnection(): void {
        this.connection = $.hubConnection(this.url);
        this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('testhub');

        // connection starts
        this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
          console.log('Connected to Hub');
      }).catch((error: any) => {
          console.log('Hub error -> ' + error);
      });

      this.connection.proxies.testHub.on('databaseUpdateNotification', () => {
        console.log('captured response');
      });
    }
}
```

I am able to see the 'Connected to Hub' message in console. I believe there is no connection issue. When .net some message broadcaster broadcasting I am not able to capture the response.

How to capture the response here?

Appreciate all your help....

Thanks a ton

Comment: Why dont you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr ?

Comment: I dont have that in our artifactory thats why trying with other option

Answer (score 0):

On your method change to:

```js
this.connection.proxies.testHub.on('databaseUpdateNotification', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```